# Example of a nowhere dense set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Does there exist a nowhere dense subset $X$ of a metric space such that complement of $X$ is not dense?

I know $X$ cannot be closed. Any ideas for general case?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829752/how-to-show-the-that-a-set-a-nowhere-dense-is-equivalent-to-the-complement-of?rq=1) help?

Comment: @DavidMitra: I don’t think so.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, I don’t think it’s duplicated

Comment: Why not? It tells you, that the answer to your question is no. Even in a more general case. David Mitra's link tells you exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is nowhere dense, even the larger set $\overline{A}$ has a dense complement. So a fortiori $A$ has a dense complement too; a superset of a dense set is dense.

So no.