# what does superscript zero in set notation?

Tags: general-topology

In [How to show the that a set $A$ nowhere dense is equivalent to the complement of $A$ containing a dense open set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829752/how-to-show-the-that-a-set-a-nowhere-dense-is-equivalent-to-the-complement-of/829763)

what does the superscripted little-bitty zero (looks like the number of degrees for temperature) mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)

Answer (score 1):

$A^o$ is the interior of A.  It's written with a small o.

The overline for closure and the superscript o for interior is  inferior two dimensional notion.  For example, 
$\overline {{\overline {A^o}}^o} = \overline {A^o}$.

Some mathematicians use $A^{o-o-} = A^{o-}$.

Answer (score 0):

The *interior* $A^o\subset A$.

Incidentally,  it is the largest open set contained in $A$;  or the union of all open sets contained in $A$.