# Understanding proof that If $X$ is locally of finite type and geometrically reduced over $k$ then $X$ contains a dense open which is smooth over $k$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Stacks's Project, Lemma 33.25.7 ( https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/056V ) and stuck at some statement (In fact, I asked question for final statement in proof of the lemma 33.25.7 under the same title and the question is resolved by my own. And I propose another question for making sure. So there can be appear radical change of contents of question and please understanding) :

**Lemma 33.25.7.** Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$. If $X$ is locally of finte type and geometrically reduced over $k$ then $X$ contains a dense open which is smooth over $k$

*Proof.* The problem is local on $X$, hence we may assume $X$ is quasi-compact. Let $X = X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_n $ be the irreudicble components of $X$. Then $Z= \cup_{i \neq j} X_i \cap X_j$ is nowhere dense in $X$. **Hence we may replace $X$ by $X -Z$. As $X-Z$ is a disjoint union of irreducible schemes, this reduces to the case where $X$ is irreducible.** As $X$ is irreducible and reduced, it is integral. ( Next proof is omitted )..

I don't understand the bold statement.

**Q.1**. Why can we replace $X$ by $X-Z$? Since $Z$ is nowhere dense, $(X-Z)^{\circ}$ is dense in $X$ ( [How to show the that a set $A$ nowhere dense is equivalent to the complement of $A$ containing a dense open set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829752/how-to-show-the-that-a-set-a-nowhere-dense-is-equivalent-to-the-complement-of)). Can we try to use this?

**EDIT** : I think that I solve this first question, by noting that $Z$ is closed so that $U:=X-Z$ is open, and the composition $U \to X \to \operatorname{Spec}k$ is locally of finite type and geometrically reduced over $k$. If needed, I will upload detailed proof. Anyway, let's accept this statement and go to next question.

**Q.2.** Why can we reduced to the case where $X$ is irreducible? Disjoint union of irreducible schemes is irreducible? Perhaps, It may not seem possible but I don't know how can we derive to the reductibility. What should I catch?

Can anyone help?

Comment: -1, you're asking questions about the definitions without having supplied them in your post. The fact that the answer comes from the definitions in the Stacks Project of what a smooth morphism is makes me believe that in addition to not having included them in this post, you haven't looked at them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is that if $X$ is locally of finite type and reduce, then there is a dense open subset of $X$ which is smooth. Most of the reductions made in argument you quote just use basic topological facts:

Since $X$ is a $k$-scheme locally of finite type, it has a covering by affine schemes, that is, $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ where $U_i$ is an open subset of $X$ and $U_i$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(R_i)$ for some finitely generated $\mathsf k$-algebra $R_i$. ( So $R_i$ is noetherian ). Thus if we can show that there is a dense open $V_i\subseteq U_i$ which is smooth, then $V:=\bigcup_{i \in I} V_i$ will be a dense open in $X$ which is smooth (because smoothness is a local property, and so $Y\subseteq X$ is smooth if and only if $Y\cap U_i$ is smooth for all $i \in I$).

This reduces us to showing that an affine scheme $X_R = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ has a dense open subset which is smooth. Now $X_R$ is a Noetherian topological space, so it is the union of finitely many maximal closed subsets, which are known as its irreducible components, say $X_R = \bigsqcup_{k=1}^n X_k$.

Now suppose $k \neq l \in \{1,2\ldots,n\}$. The intersection $X_k\cap X_l$ is a closed subset of two distinct irreducible components, hence it is nowhere dense: if $V\subset \text{int}(X_k\cap X_l)\subset X_k$ is open, then $V\cap (X_k\backslash X_l) = \emptyset$ is the intersection of open subsets of $X_k$, and since $X_k$ is irreducible, this  implies that $V=\emptyset$.
Next we use the following:

**Claim**: A finite union of nowhere dense closed subsets is nowhere dense.

By induction this reduces to showing that the union $A\cup B$ of two closed and nowhere dense subsets $A$ and $B$ is itself closed and nowhere dense. Now $A\cup B$ is clearly closed, and if $V \subseteq A\cup B$ is open, then $V\cap B^c\subseteq A$ is open and hence empty, so that $V \subseteq B$ and hence, as $B$ is nowhere dense, $V=\emptyset$. It follows that $\text{int}(A\cup B) = \emptyset$ as required.

Now let $N = \bigcup_{1\leq k<l\leq n} X_k\cap X_l$. As a finite union of closed nowhere dense sets, by the above, it is itself closed and nowhere dense. Equivalently, $X^o= X_R\backslash N$ is open and dense in $X$. Now if $Y$ is any subset of $X_R$, and $C$ an irreducible component of $Y$, then $C=Y\cap X_k$ for some $k$: Indeed $C$ is a maximal closed subset of $Y$. Thus $C = Y\cap Z$ for some closed subset $Z$ of $X_R$ which must lie in some maximal closed subset of $X_R$, say $Z\subseteq X_k$. But then $C=Y\cap Z \subseteq Y \cap X_k$, so by maximality of $C$ we have $C=Y\cap X_k$ as claimed. Thus the irreducible components of $X^o$ are $X_k^o = X_k\backslash N$, and hence are disjoint. They are therefore both open and closed in $X^o$, and so if every $X_k^o$ contains an open dense subset which is smooth, the union of these subsets will be an open dense smooth subset of $X^o$ and therefore of $X_R$.

Since $X^0_k$ is irreducible, we have reduced to the case $X$ an irreducible affine scheme as required!